# Intercepting 401 for any response in Elm

Tags: elm

I'm building an application in Elm where most API calls are protected; i.e. the user needs to be logged in for the API call to work. If the user is not logged in, they will receive a `401 Unauthorized` response. I want the application to redirect to the login page if *any* response is a 401.

Currently, I only have this redirect set up for a single API call. Here is a stripped-down version of the code to give an idea of how it's set up:

```
-- Util/Api.elm
type alias Data data =
    { data : data
    }

-- Resources/Expense.elm
getExpenses : (Progress (Api.Data (List Expense)) -> msg) -> Sub msg
getExpenses msg =
    (dataDecoder expenseListDecoder)
        |> Http.get expensesEndpoint
        |> Progress.track expensesEndpoint msg

-- Main/Msg.elm
type Msg
    = ExpenseListMsg ExpenseListMsg
    | RedirectToLogin

-- Main/Update.elm
update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        ExpenseListMsg msg ->
            ExpenseList.Update.update msg model

        GoTo path ->
            model ! [ Navigation.newUrl path ]

        RedirectToLogin ->
            model ! [ Navigation.load "path/to/login" ]

-- ExpenseList/Msg.elm
type ExpenseListMsg
    = GetExpensesProgress (Progress (Api.Data (List Expense)))
    | SetLoading

-- ExpenseList/Update.elm
update : ExpenseListMsg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        SetLoading ->
            { model | expenses = setExpensesLoading model.expenses } ! []

        GetExpensesProgress (Done { data }) ->
            { model | expenses = addExpenses model.expenses data } ! []

        GetExpensesProgress (Fail (BadStatus { status })) ->
            case status.code of
                401 ->
                    model ! [ msgToCmd RedirectToLogin ]

                _ ->
                    model ! []

        GetExpensesProgress (Fail error) ->
            model ! []

        GetExpensesProgress progress ->
            { model | expenses = setExpensesLoading model.expenses } ! []
```

Essentially, I want to move the logic around `401` responses from `ExpenseList/Update.elm` up to `Main/Update.elm` so that I can use it for any request I want.

I attempted a number of things, but nothing quite worked with Elm's type system. For example, one thing I wanted to do was try to do a nested pattern match with missing specificity in the middle, e.g.:

```
-- Main/Update.elm
update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        ApiCall (messageType (msg (Fail (BadStatus { status })))) ->
            case status of ->
              . . .
      . . .
```

I was hoping something like this would work and would match a message that looked like: `ApiCall (ExpenseListMsg (GetExpensesProgress (Fail (BadStatus))))`. Unfortunately, it's not proper Elm syntax, so my code didn't compile.

How can I write something that will allow me to mark an API call as protected and catch `401` errors at the top level in `Main.Update.update`?

Comment: try http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/simonh1000/elm-jwt/5.3.0/Jwt#promote401

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the API call is encapsulated by the `ExpenseList/Update` module. This encapsulation is what makes the API call results unavailable to the `Main` module. The interaction works like this: `Main -> FeatureModule -> API`

Because the API is what provides the information needed to determine whether the app should redirect to the login page, and you want the `Main` module to perform the redirect, the `Main` module needs access to the `API`. Hence, the encapsulation needs to go. Instead, you can:

- Have an API module which provides the low-level API functionality by producing `Task`s. Unlike producing `Cmd`s, this allows the caller, such as the `Main` module to decide how to handle the result of the `Task`, which can be acquired by converting the `Task` to a `Cmd` and giving it to the Elm runtime for execution.
- Have the `ExpenseList.Update` module use the API module to create `Tasks`.

With this arrangement:

- The `Main` module *sends* high-level commands to a feature module, which then uses the API module to produce the low-level instructions, which are then provided to the `Main` module.
- The `Main` module doesn't need to care what those low-level instructions are, it simply converts the `Task` to a `Cmd` and waits for the result.
- When the result comes back it's in a low-level format (ex. Success/Fail). At this point the `Main` module can jump in and handle the redirect on a 401 error. Otherwise, it can pass the result to a feature module so it may handle the result.